# Does there exist a temprature difference within isolated air colomns?

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas, gas

For architectural purposes, this question is vital.

If I were to construct an insulated cylinder $10\ m$ in height and $1\ m$ in radius and fill it with some fluid, and leave it for some hours, would the top of the cylinder be a higher temperature than the bottom?

I know pockets of hot air rise, but does their temperature even out with the rest of the cylinder?
I also know that the air at the top would be less dense, but I don't feel confident to try to answer this question on my own.

Comment: Why would there be pockets of hot fluid if the column is insulated?

Comment: Thermal stratification certainly happens in buildings; I expect the general case to require computational fluid dynamics, but the cylinder case might be amenable to simpler analysis. The equilibrium temperature profile would be determined by the ratio of air buoyancy and thermal conductivity, I expect. The Grashof number may also be relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grashof_number

Comment: @AndersSandberg  Do you know anyone I could ask specificaly?  THis question is very important and it seems I wouldn't be able to study to a high enough level on my own. Thanks

Comment: @ChetMiller I was simply demonstrating my current knowledge. This way my question would be answered with more accuracy.